# how to delete a salesforce commerce cloud cartridge?

Tags: commerce-cloud

I am trying to find documentation on this topic with no luck yet. I recently started a new position where I do a little of salesforce. My employer wants to terminate a contract with a third party (monetate), and they would like me to remove the monetate salesforce integration.

Does anybody knows how to delete a cartridge in Salesforce? or where I can find decent documentation?

Comment: Are you speaking about in code, or within business manager?

Comment: That's the question isn't Jeff? If there is an option in business manager I much prefer that route. I never know when I should mess with the templates versus making changes in the CRM. still learning to walk that fine line.

Comment: So, in business manager, you can remove a cartridge from the cartridge path.  https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SFRA/ConfiguringTheSFRACartridgePath.html?resultof=%22%63%61%72%74%72%69%64%67%65%22%20%22%63%61%72%74%72%69%64%67%22%20%22%70%61%74%68%22%20

Answer (score 1):

1.
You can use a WebDav client (e.g. http://winscp.net, https://cyberduck.io/) to delete a cartridge from a code version (make sure you have a backup of the code - you can download a zip archive of the code by going in **Business Manager > Administration >  Site Development >  Code Deployment** and clicking on the corresponding code version and then on the Download button). https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SiteDevelopment/CartridgeDirectoryviaWebDAV.html

2.
Ideally there should be some build/deployment routine/tool/server, which should be possible to be modified to not include the corresponding cartridge. Then you would create a new code version with this build/deployment routine/tool/server and deploy only the needed cartridges to it.

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SiteDevelopment/Managingcodeversions.html
https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SiteDevelopment/CodeDeployment.html
https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/WhitePaper/ContinuousIntegration.html

3.
Another option would be, if this is on a sandbox instance, you can connect to it using UX Studio eclipse plugin. Then if you sync your workspace with the sandbox, you get a dialog that allows you to delete cartridges from the server, which are not present in your workspace.

P.S. As Jeff have said, you should also remove the cartridge from the cartridge path, which would basically unlink the code from the corresponding site. (The above options physically remove the code from the code version you are currently using)